# How do I add files from a directory to a .zip-File using the 7zip command line?

Tags: command-line, zip, archiving, 7-zip

I am using the 7zip command line to zip-up files. How can I add all files and subdirectorys from a folder to a zip file (.jar archive file)? I used:

```
7zip.exe a -t7z file.zip C:\folder
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to use the zip format instead of the 7z format so set `-tzip` and include the path in quotes in case there is a space in the path.

```
7z.exe a -tzip "file.zip" "C:\folder"
```

Check the cmd manual for more details: http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the filenames in the appropriate place.

Here's a link explaining the command line arguments for 7-zip: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Comment: Thank you.
I know that page, I have it open in another tab.
Can I have an example maybe :-/?

Comment: 7z.exe u -t7z file.zip C:folder* -r?

Comment: Yay, that should work, but I can't test it because .jar-Files are not compatible... Thanks anyway.